# MediaWiki extension that allows me to insert adsense code into every wiki page

Tags: mediawiki

I'm looking for an extension that will allow me to insert Google AdSense code into every wiki page. I know [there is an extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Extension%3aGoogle_AdSense_2) out there that puts the code on the left side bar, but that's not what I am looking for. I also know you can make a template and insert the code into that (assuming you have HTML enabled) however that is insecure as it releases your pub ID.

Features I am looking for:

- Easy setup and config via LocalSettings.php (or another config file)
- Automatically inserts the ad into every page (configurable to where)
- (Optional) Don't show the ad to defined usergroups (eg don't show ads to users apart of the administrator group)
- Should work with the latest stable version of MediaWiki

Comment: Could you please describe what is wrong with Extension:Google_AdSense_2?